# added button to sceneKit view but it has a lag

Tags: ios, uibutton, scenekit

I added a custom button to the sceneKit view. When it is touched, it plays an animation, indicating that it was clicked. The problem I'm facing is the delay between user touch and start of animation. My scene has 28.1K triangles and 84.4K vertices. Is that to much or do I need to implement buttons differently. The scene renders with 60fps. I added the button via **sceneView.addSubview:** Thanks for answers

```
     viewDidLoad(){
     // relevant code
        starButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
        starButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)
        starButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "yellowstar.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        sceneView.addSubview(starButton)
        starButton.addTarget(self, action: "starButtonClicked", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        starButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
        }



    func starButtonClicked(){
            animateScaleDown()

        }

    func animateScaleDown(){

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
            self.starButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8)

            }, completion: { _ in
                self.wait()
        })

    }

    func wait(){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {}, completion: { _ in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
                self.starButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)

            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the touch and animation code?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: How much delay is it? If you're super sensitive you might be seeing the 2 frames of delay inherent to the SDK and iOS before the animation starts.

Comment: about half a second. Waaaaay to much for any good user experience. I as wondering, should I learn SprikeKit and use an overlaySKScene property and than add buttons to overlaySKScene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I solved it. The problematic piece of code is

```
starButton.addTarget(self, action: "starButtonClicked", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

**UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside** gives the illusion of lag. Changing it to **.TouchDown** is much better.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5

```
var starButton = UIButton()

    func a ()  {

        starButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
        starButton.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)
        starButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        SpielFenster.addSubview(starButton)

        starButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(starButtonClicked), for: UIControl.Event.touchDown)
        starButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
    }
    @objc func starButtonClicked(){
        animateScaleDown()
    }

    func animateScaleDown(){

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.starButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)

        }, completion: { _ in
            self.wait()
        })

    }

    func wait(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {}, completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.starButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)

            })
        })
    }
```