# UIView above presented SKScene - Why are touches always going through to the scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touch

I have a confusing situation. First, here's the code:

```
class MyView: SKView {
    ...
    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let gameScene = MyGameScene(...)
        // ...
        presentScene(gameScene)

        let view = UIView()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addSubview(view)
    }
    ...
}

class MyGameScene: SKScene {
    ...
    public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touch received")
    }
    ...
}
```

I have a `SKView` that's presenting a `SKScene`. After presenting it, I add a `UIView` that's filling the screen. However, when I start the app and tap on the screen, "touch received" is printed, which means the touch got through to the scene, which should be behind the `view`. Why is that?

And what can I do to prevent it?

I also tried adding a gesture recogniser to the view. It doesn't prevent the issue, though (even though I set `cancelsTouchesInView` to true)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` that should make it so that the GameScene SKView does not accept touches

Comment: I know, that's what `isUserInteractionEnabled` is there for. I *do* want it to accept touches. And if you mean disabling this on `MyGameScene`, that's not an option. The `SKView` should catch the touch and not redirect it to the scene

Comment: could you add the code for `presentSene()`

Comment: ehm, that's a method from SpriteKit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1519705-presentscene

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're trying to achieve some kind of a HUD. SceneKit is not pure UIKit so you'll need to adapt your approach - some ideas:

- `UIButton` should still work as mentioned here:
  [added button to sceneKit view but it has a lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514935/added-button-to-scenekit-view-but-it-has-a-lag)
- Tap gesture recogniser attached to `SCNView`:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42982177/5329717
- If you really need this particular `UIView` you could render it as an image and use a `SKSpriteNode` with `SKTexture` and handle touches there.
- Not really recommended, but as a last resort you could add your `UIView` directly to `UIWindow`

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, I know workarounds for this, but it bugs me because it's not how I think it's supposed to work (it likely has a reason, and I want to know about that). It just doesn't feel right to "hack" a solution for such a seemingly trivial thing as a responder chain.

Comment: Is the view inside parent's view frame? It not it wouldn't get the touch events.

Comment: Yes it is inside parent's frame

Comment: I'd subclass `SKView` to override `hitTest:withEvent:` and verify if genuine implementation iterates through it's subviews calling their `hitTest`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue gets fixed if you add the view to the superview of the `SKView` (i.e add it to the presenting view controller).

So you can try doing something along these lines:

```
let view = UIView()
view.frame = bounds
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
superview?.addSubview(view)
```

Alternatively you can add it to the window, but this is not really recommended.

Comment: This would change the coordinate system and `view.frame = bounds` wouldn't work. You'd have to convert between coordinate systems, which could get messy if it's getting complex. Also, this doesn't feel like a solution, it's just a workaround to avoid the issue :/